# Why does this does not create a default constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I am wondering why this throws an exception (at execution time):

```
IAgentIndicator iai = (IAgentIndicator)Activator.CreateInstance(agentIndicatorType);
```

When I have a constructor with default parameters (but when I don't create the constructor `public foo()` :

```
public class foo : IAgentIndicator
{
    public foo(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Is not the parameterless constructor generated at compile-time ?

Comment: "is not the parameterless constructor generated at compile-time ?" - unless you declare a constructor of your own.

Comment: Some methods require a parameter-less constructor so you may need to have two constructors.  Add : public foo(){}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is not the parameterless constructor generated at compile-time ?

As others said, a default constructor will only be generated if you haven't provided a constructor implementation yourself which takes arguments.

[From the specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608(v=vs.71).aspx) (§10.10.4)(emphasis mine):

> **If a class contains no instance constructor declarations**, a default
>   instance constructor is automatically provided. That default
>   constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct
>   base class. If the direct base class does not have an accessible
>   parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs.

If you look at the signature for your type in IL, you'll see that it creates a constructor with two parameters which are annotated with an `[opt]` tag and have default values:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
instance void .ctor (
    [opt] int32 a,
    [opt] int32 b
) cil managed 
{
    .param [1] = int32(0)
    .param [2] = int32(0)
    // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
    // Code size 9 (0x9)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006: nop
    IL_0007: nop
    IL_0008: ret
} // end of method foo::.ctor
```

This is not an empty constructor as `Activate.CreateInstance` expects.

Answer (score 8):

There are two issues here:

1. A parameterless constructor is generated automatically for you only if you don't define any constructors yourself. Clearly this is not the case here, since *you've manually declared a constructor*.
2. Optional parameters are little more than compile-time syntactic sugar at the call spot. A parameterized constructor does not count as a parameterless one, *even if all of its parameters are optional*.

Comment: Here, point 2 is the key thing. Optional parameters are translated into actual parameters where the method is called. That also means that if your method with default parameters is in a separate assembly, you change their value and then only update that assembly, the code wont' be affected as the caller methods still have *their* default parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> is not the parameterless constructor generated at compile-time

The DEFAULT parameterless constructor is only generated is no constructor is defined. As can be read in the language specifications.

Answer (score 2):

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided.

So if there is a constructor .net will not create another parameterless constructor.

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

According to the language specification for c#:

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided. That default constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct base class. If the direct base class does not have an accessible parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs.

Since your class foo contains an instance constructor no default constructor is generated.  You will need to declare your own.